# how to convert string to datetime.timedelta()?

Tags: python, timedelta

how can i convert my string of date to a `datetime.timedelta()` in Python?

I have this code :

```
import datetime

date_select = '2011-12-1'
delta = datetime.timedelta(days=1)
target_date = date_select + delta
print target_date
```

thanks in advance ...

Comment: What's wrong with the code you posted?  Your question doesn't match the example code at all.  The question asks about making a `timedelta`, but the code creates a 'datetime`.  What are you asking?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You wouldn't convert `date_select` to a `timedelta`, instead, you need a `datetime` object, which can be added to a `timedelta` to produce an updated `datetime` object:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

date_select = datetime.strptime('2011-12-1', '%Y-%m-%d')
delta = timedelta(days=1)
target_date = date_select + delta
print target_date
```

Or, if you prefer, without the fancy `from ... import ...` import line:

```
import datetime    # <- LOOK HERE, same as in your example

date_select = datetime.datetime.strptime('2011-12-1', '%Y-%m-%d')
delta = datetime.timedelta(days=1)
target_date = date_select + delta
print target_date
```

Comment: thanks for the reply Adam, but it also not working.. i got this error : `AttributeError: type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'timedelta'` do you have any ideas?

Comment: @gadss, Sorry, that's because I've imported timedelta from datetime.  You can either use your original import line, and change the strptime to `datetime.datetime.strptime(...)` or change your timedelta line to `timedelta(...)` (notice, no `datetime.`).   The example I've given should work though.

Comment: when i print the `target_date` this will come out `2011-12-01 00:00:00` is there any way that only the `2011-12-01` will be return to `target_date`? thanks ...

Answer (score 0):

You use `strptime` to do this.

```
from datetime import datetime

target_date = datetime.strptime(date_select, '%Y-%m-%d')
```

Comment: `AttributeError: type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'timedelta'` this is what i have got.. thanks blender

Comment: I can run this code just fine on Python2 and Python3. Do you have any more code?

Comment: @gadss, that's because `datetime` in his example (notice the different import line) is the object/type and not the module `datetime`.  This can be a bit confusing if you aren't used to using this module, but the object/type and the module have exactly the same name.

Comment: @AdamWagner, with "from datatime import datetime", still got this error. With this log, strptime cannot translate timedelta to string.

Answer (score 0):

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

date_select = '2011-12-1'
new_data = datetime.strptime(date_select, '%Y-%m-%d')
delta = timedelta(days=1)

target_date = date_select + delta
print target_date
```

You will get 2011-12-02 00:00:00; to strip off the '00:00:00' and get only the date, just add .date() to target_date

```
print target_date.date()
```

This should give you the only the date = `2011-12-02`